# Smoothening plot in gnuplot with pm3d

Tags: gnuplot

When plotting an X,Y,Z data set as color map I need to smoothen the plot a bit. The data are sparse and I need some sort of gaussian blur applied to the result.

Using following code :

```
reset
#set zrange [2:6]
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels incr 2.0,0.5,8.0

set view map
set xrange [0:2184]
set yrange [0:1472]

set dgrid3d 100,100,4

set table "ap130_base_contour.txt"
splot 'ap130_base.dat' using 11:12:14
unset table

unset contour
set surface
set table "ap130_base_dgrid.txt"
splot 'ap130_base.dat' using 11:12:14
unset table

reset
set pm3d map
unset key
set palette defined (0 '#352a87', 1 '#0363e1',2 '#1485d4', 3 '#06a7c6', 4 '#38b99e', 5 '#92bf73', 6 '#d9ba56', 7 '#fcce2e', 8 '#f9fb0e')
set autoscale fix
set grid

set terminal png size 2184,1472 enhanced font "Helvetica,20"
set output 'ap130_base.png'

splot 'ap130_base_dgrid.txt' w pm3d, 'ap130_base_contour.txt' w l lc rgb "black"

set output
set  terminal X11
```

The plot looks like this;

[image]

Is there a way to make this less 'spotty'?

Your input is much appreciated.
Gert.

Comment: Try to Increase the sampling of your `dgrid3d` call

Comment: `dgrid3d` offers different smoothing kernels with adjustable scale parameters, including a Gaussian kernel (see `help dgrid3d`).

Comment: I wanted to add that the dgrid3d solution works. My data points are really sparse and I got best results with gauss 100 smoothening. Also want to note that the row,col parameters confused me at first. These are not the step size of the derived grid but the number of grid points per axis. (sort of 1/step).